# With the Facebook OpenGraph, is there a way to get friends checkins through Real-Time Updates?

Tags: facebook, real-time, facebook-opengraph, checkin

I am working on an app that is integrating the Facebook OpenGraph.  I'm trying to subscribe to Real-Time Updates so that I can have my app automatically updated whenever friends of my users check in somewhere.

It appears that Connections are available in realtime with the User Object and checkins are a connection but through the OpenGraph Explorer I can only see checkins where people have tagged myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe to realtime updates, Facebook only sends you data about the users who have taken actions in your app, not their friends.

But you will get all updates about a user which has added your app - which includes when one of their friends tags them in a checkin - along with that user's own checkins.